# Corda 3.3 and Open JDK

Tags: corda

Corda 3.3 is not working with openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
I'm able to build the cordapp, start it and also list all the flows using flow list command. However, when I try to run any flow in the shell I'm getting following exceptions and stack trace

[ERROR] 12:02:15+0530 [pool-8-thread-2] command.CRaSHSession.execute - Error while evaluating request 'flow start WhoAmI' flow start WhoAmI: exception: UndeclaredThrowableException
...
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target
...
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target

Comment: Corda require at least version Java JVM 8u171

Comment: What OpenJDK version? Is it a build from Azul? https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/

Comment: I'm getting the following when I run java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.12.1, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 8.1 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190205_265 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 90dd8cb40
OMR      - d2f4534b
JCL      - d002501a90 based on jdk8u202-b08)

Comment: Corda 4 supports OpenJDK https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting Corda 4, the support for Open JDK has been added.

See here for more details: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/getting-set-up.html